# Как найти строку с комментарием вида "<--" ?..

Tags: javascript, dom

Средствами javascript?..
Комментарий может находится в любой части html-документа как в хид, так и в боди, находится в начале строки.

Comment: [Доступ к комментариям HTML](http://hashcode.ru/questions/131180/доступ-к-комментариям-html)

Comment: хорошо, но интересует также алгоритм перебора всех элементов ДОМа для поиска комментариев, НО! без фреймворков, нужен чистый жаваскрипт

Comment: так принятый ответ содержит этот алгоритм и минимум jQuery, просто пройтись надо не по div`ам, а по всему документу

Comment: тот алгоритм хорош, чтобы внутри контейнера лазить, но никак по всему ДОМу.слабость алгоритма - в отсутствии обработки уровней вложенности.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

И вновь отвечаю сам себе:

```
var allComments = []; // массив результатов
getElems(document);
console.log(allComments);

function getElems(el) { // рекурсивная функция, 
    // которая обходит все уровни вложенности ДОМ
    var chNodes, i;
    if (el.nodeType == 8) { // это код ноды-комментария
        allComments.push(el.nodeValue); // прячем в массив сам комментарий, 
        // можно сделать еще что-то
    }
    if (el.hasChildNodes()) {
        chNodes = el.childNodes;
        for (i = 0; i < chNodes.length; i++) {
            getElems(chNodes[i]);
        }
    }
}
```

Всем спасибо за внимание.

Comment: можно закрывать вопрос.